# How do i make the image appear at the same time as the next and to be on the rightt

Tags: javascript, html, css

The loading screen is loading to high up it needs to be under the menu section of the page to make it look more realistic, and how do I make the image appear at the same time as the text cause the image after the loading always comes up first
[image: The loading screen is to high up]HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<HTML lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="dropdownmenu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="rainbowheading.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="loadingcss.css">
<script src="loading.js"></script>
<title> North Macedonia </title>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="rainbow"> The pearl of the Balkans: Macedonia </h1>
  <div class="navbar">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">Macedonian Dispora</a>
  <a href="cities.html">Cities</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">History
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Ancient History</a>
      <a href="#">Ottoman Period</a>
      <a href="#">Yugoslav Period</a>
      <a href="#">Modern History</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">
<div id="loader"></div>

<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
  <h2>Welcome to my website about Macedonia</h2>
  <p>x</p>

</div>
<div style="display:none;" id="MyDi" class="animate-bottom">
 <img src="./images/ohridindex.jpg" class="center">
 </body>
```

CSS (For loading) This is the main CSS document

```
/* Center the loader */
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom { 
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#myDi {
  display: Float;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("myDi").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: I don't see any CSS targeting your `#loader` div. Most of the CSS you've posted relates to the dropdown, which doesn't sound like the piece you're having trouble with. Creating a more minimal reproduction of your issue might help.

Comment: Fixed are you able to find out how to move the loader under the menu bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of approaches you can take. The current code says explicitly: "put `#loader` 200px below the top of the document" because of the `top` and `position` css properties. You could increase the `top` number to move it further down.

If you wanted to guarantee the loader is below the menu bar, even if the menu bar changes size, you could put it inside a relatively positioned div and remove the `top` property, which will make it display above the other content, but positioned relatively to the wrapper element ([read more about positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning)).

```html
<!-- the navbar goes here -->
<div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader" />
<div>
```

```css
#loader-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

Another note about your code - make sure all your visible content is wrapped in your `<body>`. Right now your navbar is inside the `<head>`, which isn't valid.

Comment: Do you know how I can add an image to appear at the exact time as the text, with the image on the right of the text? anytime i try to do it the image always appears before the text

Answer (score 0):

```
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 200px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Loader icon is loading in center of screen. 
I see the HTML code. But The div in header should be placed in body tag.